# Resize event not firing after binding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using bind on `bind` on jQuery to click and resize listeners with unique namespace - so I can unbind them safely.

When pressing click - it is logging the **"Mouse Clicked"** message.

But when changing the window size - nothing happans.

```
class MyView {
    constructor() {
        $(window.document).on('click.myView', this._onDocumentClick.bind(this));
        $(window.document).on('resize.myView', this._onDocumentResize.bind(this));
        $('#clean').on('click', this._cleanup.bind(this));
    }
    _cleanup() {
        $(window.document).unbind('resize.myView');
        $(window.document).unbind('click.myView');
    }
    _onDocumentResize() {
        console.log('Window Resized'); //Not reaching here
    }
    _onDocumentClick() {
        console.log('Mouse Clicked'); //OK
    }
}
```

Any ideas what is the difference between the `resize` and `click` event?

Comment: Pls show the code that triggers the events.

Comment: its simple: new MyView();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `resize` event is fired by the `window` object, not the `window.document` object :) therefore, this should work:

```
$(window).bind('resize.myView', this._onWindowResize.bind(this));
```

p/s: In your initial event handler binding, you seem to have swapped the callback and the events, i.e. `resize` triggering the private click method, and vice versa.

Even better: don't use `.bind()` anymore, newer versions of jQuery recommends using `.on()`, i.e.:

```
$(window).on('resize.myView', this._onWindowResize.bind(this));
```